# Detect If Return/Enter Key Is Pressed on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard-events

I want to capture the press of the Enter key. For the `keyDown:` and `keyUp:` methods, when I output the `NSEvent` I get 36 as the value, but when I try to do something with that value it's unresponsive. Does anyone know what the value is and how to accomplish this with the keyDown/keyUp methods? I was looking for some sort of mapping of the keys but I couldn't find one.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean when you say "when I try to do something with that value it's unresponsive".  Maybe show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString *eventChars = [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers];
    unichar keyChar = [eventChars characterAtIndex:0];

    if (( keyChar == NSEnterCharacter ) ||
        ( keyChar == NSCarriageReturnCharacter ))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried the NSEnterCharacter check before, but to no avail. The NSCarriageReturnCharacter value works irregardless of using `[theEvent characters]` which is what I had used vs `[theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers]`, which is what you used. Weird.

Thanks for the quick reply too :)